# POS count of first word in sentences using SPACY

Tags: python, spacy

Intent is to check the POS of first word of sentences and return the POS count of it using Spacy.

Effort so far:

```
import spacy
from collections import Counter
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("The cat slept well. Dog is good.")
for sent in doc.sents:
    for token in sent:
        if token.i == 0:
            c = Counter(([token.pos_ for token in sent for sent in doc.sents]))
            print (c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'DET': 2, 'NOUN': 2, 'VERB': 2, 'ADV': 2, 'PUNCT': 2})
```

Considering POS for 'the' is DET and 'Dog' is PROPN

Desired output:

```
    DET: 1
    PROPN: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` condition evaluates to `True` only for the first token of the first sentence. The `Counter` counts POS tags of the tokens of the first sentence twice (i.e. # of sentences). That's why your `Counter` outputs the value `2` for all tags.

Here is the code doing what you want:

```
from collections import Counter
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("The cat slept well. Dog is good.")
c = Counter((sent[0].pos_ for sent in doc.sents))
print(c)
```